# HTML input "type=file" behaviour iOS 8.4 & 9.2

Tags: ios, file-upload, uiwebview

I am loading my website inside UIWebview in iOS using Xamarin.Forms. In my website I have `input type="file"` attributes in many places to upload files like docx, ppt, pdf etc...

I have installed Dropbox & Onedrive app in both iOS 8.4 & 9.2 devices. When I click button which contains `type=file` attribute I am seeing different behavior in iOS 9.2 & 8.4

**iOS 9.2**

[image]

**iOS 8.4:**

[image]

As you see, in 9.2 it automatically detects installed iCloud storage apps and listing it and I am able to upload files successfully, whereas in 8.4 even though iCloud storage app exist, it doesn't list it.

Above screenshot is taken from W3.org website. Same thing happening in my app also.

**This may be very basic, I put enough effort to search on this, but couldn't find anything.**

Answer (score 2):

This only works on iOS 9+.

TBH it was a pain in the ass to find this info and I can't seem to find it again...

Maybe you can use https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin for iOS8.

Comment: Great answer. I think using the plugin you suggested along with Cordova's Camera and File Chooser plugins can do a pretty good job !